# Output of System.Drawing.Image Save is not the same as what fed into Image.FromStream

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-core, .net-core, xss

I am trying to validate an image submitted to backend in Base64 string format by parsing it into an Image object, extracting it from the same Image object and finally comparing input byte array and output byte array assuming these two should be the same or there was something wrong in the input image. Here is the code:

```
    private void UpdatePhoto(string photoBase64) 
    {
        var imageDataInBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(photoBase64);
        ValidateImageContent(imageDataInBytes);
    }


    private void ValidateImageContent(byte[] imageDataInBytes)
    {
        using (var inputMem = new MemoryStream(imageDataInBytes))
        {
            var img = Image.FromStream(inputMem, false, true);

            using (MemoryStream outputMemStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                img.Save(outputMemStream, img.RawFormat);
                var outputSerialized = outputMemStream.ToArray();

                if (!outputSerialized.SequenceEqual(imageDataInBytes))
                    throw new Exception("Invalid image. Identified extra data in the input. Please upload another photo.");
            }
        }
    }
```

and it fails on an image that I know is a valid one.

Is my assumption wrong that output of Image.Save must be the same as what Image.FromStream is fed with? Is there a way to correct this logic to achieve this way of validation correctly?

Comment: _“an image that I know is a valid one”_ – What is a valid image? What are you actually trying to validate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compare the original image with the created image, you will notice a few differences in the metadata: For my sample image, I could observe that some metadata was stripped (XMP data was completely removed). In addition, while the EXIF data was preserved, the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) it is written in was reversed from little endian to big endian. This alone explains why the data won’t match.

In my example, the actual image data was identical but you won’t be able to tell easily from just looking at the bytes.

If you wanted to produce a result identical to the source, you would have to produce the metadata in the exact same way as the source did. You won’t be able to do so without actually looking closely at the metadata of the original photo though. .NET’s `Image` simply isn’t able to pertain all the metadata that a file could contain. And even if you were able to extract all the metadata and store it in the right format again, there are lots of fine nuances between metadata serializers that make it very difficult to produce the exact same result.

So if you wanted to compare the images, you should probably strip the metadata and just compare the image data. But then, when you think about how you save the image (`Raw`), then you will just get the exact same blob of data again, so I wouldn’t expect differences there.